# Facing error pushing branch to remote repo

Tags: gitlab

When trying to push my changes from a feature branch to the remote repo, I get the error "remote: GitLab: Author 'xxxxxxxxxx.net' is not a member of team" (I am an owner of the repo) and another error "pre-receive hook declined". I am able to interact and push branches to other projects on Gitlab, but not this particular project I am working on. And I am an owner of the GitLab org. Any suggestions please?

I tried doing a force push, created a new branch and switched to it to push the changes, cloned the project in another location, added my username and email on Git, checked if there was any protection on the branches